# Selectivizr.js won't work in respond.js

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, selectivizr, respond.js

I'm using [Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) so that I can create a responsive page in **IE8**. And it works fine.

But, I am also using [Selectivizr.js](http://selectivizr.com/) so that I can use CSS3 `:nth-child` selector in **IE8**, which also works fine.

The problem is that the `nth-child` selector won't work if it is in a *responsive point*.

For example, this **won't** work:

```
@media screen and (min-width:980px){

    .center_crni_linkovi a:nth-child(4n){
        margin:10px 0px 10px 10px;
    }

    .center_crni_linkovi a:nth-child(4n+1){
       margin:10px 10px 10px 0;
    }

}
```

But if I put the *style* outside the *responsive point*, it **works** fine. But then I can't use a *specific style* for this specific *responsive point*.

How to make it work ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A little late to the party, but if anyone else stumbles across this problem. It is a known issue with the current stable release of selectivizr when combined with respond.js. Use the latest build of selectivizr found here: https://github.com/keithclark/selectivizr/blob/master/selectivizr.js

Ensure you're loading selectivizr before respond.js and this should fix the issue.

Update:

see also this: [selectivizr2: Selectivizr with maintenance](https://github.com/corysimmons/selectivizr2) (more up to date)